# Cannot post question on SO: "Code not properly formatted as code"

Tags: support, code-formatting

I want to ask the question below on Stack Overflow, but I'm getting an error message:

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

How can the question be modified?

---

hi, I'm beginner spring user.

1. local build (spring maven) and make war file.

---

org.apache.tomcat
        tomcat-coyote
        7.0.14
    
    
        org.apache.tomcat
        tomcat-jdbc
        8.0.26

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId> 
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId> 
    <version>3.0.1</version> 
    <scope>provided</scope> 
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
    <artifactId>jolokia-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

src/main/java
    
      
        src/main/java
        
          **/*.java
        
      
      
        src/main/resources
      
      
        src/main/resources-${environment}
      
    
    
      
        maven-war-plugin
        2.2
        
          WebContent
          false
        
      
      
        maven-compiler-plugin
        3.0
        
          1.7
          1.7
          -Xlint:all
           true
           true
           UTF-8

```
  <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.1</version>
          <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
          </configuration>
</plugin>            
<plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <configuration>
         <url> /couchLogServer </url>
         <server>couchLogServer</server>
    </configuration>
```

2. upload ElasticBeanstalk my war file (java 7, tomcat 7)

### 3. but error

```
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
```

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/app.com does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:5145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5330)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Sep 24, 2015 2:54:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/app-server]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)

### at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Where maven build tomcat server.xml route setting ?
and error message 
Document base /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/app.com does not exist

Can you modify the path settings from?

Comment: What does the error message say when you read the error message?

Comment: I run the ctrl + k error is not corrected

Comment: Downvoters / Close Voters: note that this is NOT a programming question, but a question on _how_ to post the question on SO!

Comment: What happens if you *select* your code and *then* hit Ctrl-K?

Comment: This is still a mess. You should also use blockquotes for the error messages, and no idea what is "org.apache.tomcat tomcat-coyote 7.0.14 org.apache.tomcat tomcat-jdbc 8.0.26" but it's probably also detected as code.

Comment: @S.L.Barth That's why I voted as "pertains to a specific site," and not regular off-topic. This doesn't apply to many SE sites, just SO (and a few others, but mainly SO)

Answer (score 4):

I'll try breaking down your question, perhaps that will help you understand how difficult it is to follow and what's missing from it.

> hi, I'm beginner spring user.

This adds nothing useful to the question, it's best removed. What we want is a short explanation of the problem in proper sentences.

> 1. local build (spring maven) and make war file.

Here we just launch into something that isn't even a complete sentence.

Then we get your maven pom although you don't explain that's what you're giving us and it's not formatted in such a way that we can read it in the question so it seems like only a small part of it is present. You don't explain why you think that we would need this or why you think the problem may be somewhere in there.

> 2. upload ElasticBeanstalk my war file (java 7, tomcat 7)

Another incomplete sentence. What exactly are you doing here? How are you using ElastiBeanstalk? Where are you putting the war file? What is the war file called? What files are in the war?

> 3. but error

Yet more incomplete explanation. How about "When I start the web application server I get the following error in the xxxx.log file"?

You provide the error but no further explanation. Is there a directory/file at /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/app.com? If so what permissions does it have?

> Where maven build tomcat server.xml route setting ? and error message Document base /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/app.com does not exist

This is hard to read. What do you mean? What does your server.xml look like? Is it in the war file? What route setting are you talking about? Did you check whether the file/directory actually does exist? You should do all this research for us prior to asking the question and present it in the question for us.

> Can you modify the path settings from?

What path settings? Modify them from what?

Ideally we need a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) in order to understand the problem. Your pom seems much larger than would be required for that and there's no other source to determine what or where the error is. Don't send us all your code, cut it down to the minimal part that shows what the issue is.

We're not mind readers and you're competing for our attention; your competition being simpler, shorter, better written questions that are easier to answer.

Why would we allow you to post something that we'll only downvote (as unclear or not useful), close (as unclear what you're asking) and eventually delete.